# Using module attributes instead of context in ExUnit

Tags: elixir

I know in Elixir it's recommended to set the context if you want DRY your tests and to share data between the them( http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html).

The problem with this approach is that you can't use `context[:key]` directly in a pattern matching( you'll get a compile error `cannot invoke remote function Access.get/2 inside match`). Because of this you still need an extra step to assign `context[:key]` to a variable each time you want to use the context variable for a pattern match( not so DRY)

Another option for sharing data between tests are module attributes( http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html). You simply define an `@key <value>` and use it in the tests as `@key`( and at compile time the @key will be replace with the `<value>` you specified)

I was wondering if it's a good idea to use them for this purpose since so far I have not seen others doing it.
What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

So, first thing, I would probably switch to Elixir 1.1 or 1.2. There are map improvements there. You linked to the 1.0 docs, which are somewhat dated.

Second thing is, you can use pattern-matching to grab the variable from the context. Here's an example from the [1.2 ExUnit docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/1.2.0/ExUnit.Case.html):

```
defmodule KVTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  setup do
    {:ok, pid} = KV.start_link
    {:ok, [pid: pid]}
  end

  test "stores key-values", %{pid: pid} do
    assert KV.put(pid, :hello, :world) == :ok
    assert KV.get(pid, :hello) == :world
  end
end
```

The second argument to the test is the context, but instead of accessing the pid member you're matching out the pid. Now you can use it just like a normal variable. You can pattern match on it and pin it. It's more than DRY, you're declaring exactly what bit of the context you're depending on. It's more concise and more explicit.

I really recommend reading the 1.2 docs, as they have a ton more examples.

Comment: Actually this happened when I was using 1.2. I had both the 1.0 and 1.2 docs open and I pasted the 1.0 link by accident.